# R shinyapps.io: Expire date in R shinyapps.io subscription

Tags: r, shinyapps

I want to subscribe one month shinyapps.io Standard Plan. In payment part, whitch expires should I choice. For example, I want start use standard plan from September 20th to October 20th. Should October be chosen for expiration?
https://www.shinyapps.io/